# Weight Multiple columns by different range of factors

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe, df, with 3 columns. A, B and C. I want to create a weighted average column but test different weights (weights need to equal to 100%).

So I can do;

```
weights  =np.arange(0,1,0.05)
if i+j+k=1:

for i in weights:
     for j in weights:
         for k in weights:
outname=str(i)+'A'+str(j)+'B'+str(k)+'C'

df[outname]=df['A'].multiply(k)+df['B'].multiply(i)+df['C'].multiply(j)
else:
    pass
```

However the number of columns may change to a larger number. Therefore this method will stop working.

Can anyone see a clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], columns=['A','B','C'])
weightpool = np.arange(0,1,0.05)
weights =  np.linspace(0, 0, num=df.columns.size)


for times in range(1,3):
    #all weights sum up to 1
    while weights.sum()!=1:
        #choose weights out of pool
        for i in range(len(weights)-1):
            weights[i] = weightpool[randint(0, len(weightpool)-1)]

    for i in range(len(weights)-1):
        outname =  outname + str(weights[i]) + df.columns[i]
        outvalue = df[df.columns[i]].multiply(weights[i])
        df[outname] = pd.Series(outvalue, index=df.index)

df
```

Comment: thanks! I think this will work. I'm very new to python, so will try and work through it